# Select from mysql table using data from another table

Tags: mysql

I need to select results from my users table and order them by a rating that is stored in rtgitems. In the users table each user has a unique ID that is used in the rtgitems in the item column like this rt_(ID from users table).

Here is the code that I use to select from the users table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `approved` = 1 ORDER BY ");
```

Here is the code to get the ratings from the rtgitems table

```
SELECT `item`
       , (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank` 
FROM `rtgitems` 
ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC
```

Comment: This has been answered many times. Try a search.

Comment: I did, I couldn't find anything. I always do a search first before posting

Comment: You just need to use an inner join. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm new to mysql, so I am not even sure where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this should return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT u.*
     , r.totalrate/r.nrrates AS `rank`
  FROM users u
  JOIN rtgitems r
    ON r.user_id = u.id
 WHERE u.approved = 1
 ORDER BY r.totalrate/r.nrrates DESC, u.id ASC
```

---

Briefly: the `JOIN` operator specifies that rows from the two tables (users and rtgitems) should be "matched" based on the predicates in the `ON` clause.

Whenever more than one table is referenced in a query, best practice is qualify ALL column references. It's usually easiest to assign a unique alias to each table reference. (That's the short name `u` and `r` given to the users table and the rtgitems tables, respectively. References to columns in those tables are preceded with the alias and dot (period).

Comment: The problem is that in the id field of users it is just a number, but in rtgitems it is rt_ and then the number

Comment: that is not bringing up any results

Comment: never mind, it's just because the id field is actually user_id, so I got it. Thanks for your help